# PHP SQLServer Stored Procedure não executa corretamente

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando Laravel Framework Handler do meu Backend e encontrei o seguinte erro.

Meu Banco de Dados SqlServer Express 2008 R2 possui uma stored procedure que realiza uma série de rotinas e insere os dados já formatados em uma tabela. A stored procedure recebe uma Chave (Varchar) e o ano (int) do relatório que quero gerar.

Quando eu executo a stored procedure pelo script do Banco de Dados a inserção ocorre corretamente e tenho todos os dados.

```
exec indicador.usp_indicador_101_1 'asdfgh', 2015
```

Após a execução da procedure eu executo um método que realiza o seguinte select:

```
select * from indicador.T101_Indicador where A101_chave = 'asdfgh'
```

No cenário ideal eu tenho todos os resultados retornados corretamente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando eu executo pelo PHP o mesmo código:

```
<?php
$server = "###.###.###.#";
$options = array(  "UID" => "usuario",  "PWD" => "senha",  "Database" => "meubanco");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $options);  

// Then execute the procedure
$proc = "exec indicador.usp_indicador_101_1 '147896311212', 2015";
$proc_result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $proc );
// Etc...
//mssql_free_statement($proc);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Eu tenho apenas o retorno de uma linha:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A Stored procedure faz as inserções por si só, o select dos dados é feito em outro momento. As fotos apresentadas são de selects feitos no script do banco de dados.

Eu tentei de várias formas a execução da stored procedure, minha ultima tentativa foi esta com o PHP puro e o retorno é sempre o mesmo, apenas uma linha.

A seleção na aplicação é feita por um método utilizando os recursos do Laravel:

```
public static function T101_indicador($chave){

$dados = T101_indicador::where('A101_Chave', '=', $chave)
->orderBy('A101_Nomord')
->get();

//dd($dados);

return $dados;
}
```

Comment: Não ta faltando nada nesse código? não teria um `fetch_array()` por ai?

Comment: A procedure em sí não tem retorno, eu executo um select na tabela depois pra acessar os dados e acredito que lá eu deveria utilizar o fetch_array().

Comment: Então o problema é no select e não na SP, coloca ai na pergunta o resto do código.

Comment: Eu rodei este código e dei o select no script do Banco e ele retorna apenas uma linha.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi meu problema, segue o novo código:

```
$chave = (string) $chave;

$server = "enderecobanco";
$options = array(  "UID" => "usuario",  "PWD" => "senha",  "Database" => "bancodedados");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $options);

// Then execute the procedure
$proc = "{call $procedure(?,?)}";
  $params = array(&$chave, &$argumento);
  $statement = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $proc, $params);

sqlsrv_execute($statement);//Precisa executar Duas vezes para gerar todos os dados.
sqlsrv_execute($statement);

sqlsrv_close($conn);//fecha conexão
```

foi preciso adicionar "&" antes do array de parâmetros, segundo este [site](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2010/11/23/why-pass-parameters-by-reference-in-the-sqlsrv-driver/) e utilizar o método sqlsrv_execute() duas vezes, ao invés de sqlsrv_query(). Não entendo o por que de ser necessário a execução dupla. Sem esta execução dupla o código não tem o resultado correto.